# Changing a value in a column to zero when the corresponding value in another column is empty

Tags: r

I have a dataset with 4 columns. If in one column a particular cell is empty, the value in another columns should be replaced with 0.
For example:

```
df <- data.frame(rbind(c('A', '','W','1'),c('A','','W', '3'),c('A', 'BK','R','4'),c('B','BN','T', '12')))
```

The result should be this dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(rbind(c('A', '','W','0'),c('A','','W', '0'),c('A', 'BK','R','4'),c('B','BN','T', '12')))
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Usually just `df[df$X2 == "", "V4"] <- 0` but your data set seem to have factors instead of numbers. In either-way, you should Google this as this 101 question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming that your data frame really consists of factors, then you can perform following steps:

1) add '0' level to the 4th column
2) on rows where 2nd column empty, write 0 to 4th column

```
# create the sample data frame
df <- data.frame(rbind(c('A', '','W','1'),c('A','','W', '3'),c('A', 'BK','R','4'),c('B','BN','T', '12')))

# add a new level to the 4th column factor
df[, 4] <- factor(df[, 4], levels=c(levels(df[, 4]), '0'))

# write 0 to 4th column where 2nd column is ''
df[df[, 2] == '',4] <- '0'
```

If you do not need factors, you could convert the variables to character and make your life a bit easier...

In case your columns are of the class `character` in the first place, you can do just:

`df[df[, 2] == '',4] <- '0'`

As suggested by David in comments to your question

Comment: The data frame consists of factors. The problem with this formula is that in 4th column, all values that not should be zero, are now <NA>.

Comment: Not on my computer

Comment: I am quite sure it returns the correct result. Have you copied the code correctly? Also, could the down voter please explain the reason for the down vote?

Comment: The values in the 4th column are generated by the function count(). Could this be the problem?

Comment: Is the class of your 4th column really a factor? Or is it just in the case when the df is created from the code posted in the question?

Comment: If you run `class(df[, 4])`, is the result character of factor? My solution returns the error you report when the class is character.

Comment: if I run class(df[,4]) it gives factor

Comment: And if you copy and run the entire solution i posted, including the creation of df, you do get an error?

Comment: What if I would like to divide the value in the 4th column by 2 instead of converting it to 0?

Comment: You would have to convert the data in 4th column from factor to character, then to numeric. Afterwards you would do something like `df[df[, 2] == '',4] <- df[df[, 2] == '',4] /2`